# Using let instead of var breaks User:*/vector.js in MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki

I try to understand what's going on with my adaption of the [basic example](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gadget_kitchen#Write_your_first_user_script) of a MediaWiki user script.

It works in the original form, but when I replace `var` by `let` in the `format_words` function, it stops working. I'm quite new to JavaScript and jQuery. Here is the working version:

```js
function format_words(title, numWords){
  var text = title+" ("+numWords+" words)";
  return text;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var numWords = $("#mw-content-text > div").text().split(" ").length;
  var header = $("#firstHeading").text();
  $("#firstHeading").text(format_words(header, numWords));
});
```

And here the version that doesn't work

```js
function format_words(title, numWords){
  let text = title+" ("+numWords+" words)";
  return text;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var numWords = $("#mw-content-text > div").text().split(" ").length;
  var header = $("#firstHeading").text();
  $("#firstHeading").text(format_words(header, numWords));
});
```

The first gives leads to this h1 heading:

> User:Wolf/vector.js (74 words)

the second gives

> User:Wolf/vector.js

I tested this in MediaWiki 1.31.6 and in MediaWiki 1.35.0-wmf.34 (6ff15fd), same effect.

After slowly getting familiar with jQuery, I expect a lot of asynchrony, but at this point I cannot figure out its influence.

### Counter example

When I tested similar code in local HTML+JavaScript (with hot jQuery), switching from `var` to `let` doesn't break the code.

### Console log

Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104157/how-does-replacing-var-by-let-break-my-mediawiki-userscript?noredirect=1#comment109840187_62104157) I changed my script to

```js
function format_words(title, numWords){
  console.log("format_words [enter]");
  let text = title+" ("+numWords+" words)";
  console.log("format_words: text:"+text);
  return text;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("on ready [enter]");
  var numWords = $("#mw-content-text > div").text().split(" ").length;
  var header = $("#firstHeading").text();
  $("#firstHeading").text(format_words(header, numWords));
  console.log("on ready [leave]");
});
```

... and opened the console. For the `let` version it shows the following error:

```
JavaScript parse error: Parse error: Missing ; before statement in file↵
 'User:Wolf/vector.js' on line 3 vector.js line 1 > scriptElement:1:8
    <anonym> https://some.wiki/w/User:Wolf/vector.js line 1 > scriptElement:1
    jQuery 9
        DOMEval
        globalEval
        runScript
        fire
        add
        always
        checkCssHandles
        execute
        implement
    <anonym> https://some.wiki/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=user&↵
skin=vector&user=Wolf&version=0hjxbj8:1
```

I read this as `let` not being supported by JavaScript. Very strange: I was sure that JavaScript comes from the browser? And it worked with my Counter example.

**What is going on here?**

Comment: To be honest switching `var` to `let` or `const` in this case shouldn't make any difference. Are you sure that's the only change?

Comment: Absolutely I'm checking analog cases for two days now, so not only double-checked. I use the revert function and when I look at the diff (before save), I get the confirmation that **only this one word** has changed.

Comment: can you create fiddle or stackblitz demo

Comment: As stated in Counter example, the issue is not reproducible outside MediaWiki, so I guess something in the HTML delivered makes the browser downgrade to some ancient JS.

Answer (score 3):

The [JS minifier](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Architecture#JavaScriptMinifier) used by MediaWiki does not support ES6 language features like `let`.

The console error you see is an error generated by the (server-side) minifier, transferred as a script.

Comment: Good to know that this "spook" seems to have a reasonable explanation! Can you please explain this a bit, give a link for deepen my knowledge? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder why this restriction is not openly communicated where any serious MediaWiki UserScript novice (I'm not talking about copy and paste experts) will start. In the current JavaScript tutorials the advantages of 'let' are propagated so conspicuously that I find it rather ignorant if you let people run into the wall first. I understand that ES6 support is a work in progress for you MediaWiki developers, but please show me the place where the information about the current restrictions is publicly accessible.

Comment: BTW: in the preview before saving the `vector.js` both variants work as expected, another confusing detail.

Comment: MediaWiki has a part called the ResourceLoader [1] (anything called from `load.php`). The ResourceLoader will check your code for correctness and it will minify your code. If you are writing Less styles, it also compiles those. your problem comes in on the checking for correctness part, because the ResourceLoader does not know the lates JS features (aka no ES6 and therefore no `let`). It then thinks your JS is not correct, and instead of serving the supposedly broken JS, it servers some script that logs a error to the console.


  [1]: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader

Comment: I suppose previewed code does not go through the minifier? I would have expected otherwise; probably more a bug than a feature.

Comment: If you have already done a documentation search, you probably have a good idea where you'd have expected this information. Feel free to add it there, it's a wiki.

Comment: I didn't do a documentation search, I learned this many years ago. IIRC the reason why preview works is that it directly injects the JS into the page without going through the ResourceLoader for cache reasons. To find the exact answer, I would have to search the documentation, this comes from my head.

Comment: Any idea why `const` is treated as valid pendant to `var`?

Comment: @FO-nTTaX that was meant for Wolf as he might have the best idea now what the intuitive place for this information would be. Re: preview, I would have expected it to work via `ParserOptions::setupFakeRevision` overriding the page content and ResourceLoader picking that up. But I might have been remembering [c347441](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/mediawiki/core/+/347441) which never landed.

Answer (score 0):

While [Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62107378/2932052) may have (somehow) answered my original phrasing of the question

> How can using let instead of var break my MediaWiki userScript?

... I must somehow cope with this surprising limitation.<sup>1</sup> And luckily I found a quite satisfying **workaround**: **`const` is supported by the JS minifier** despite being [an ES6 feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ES2015)!

---

<sup>1</sup> that I'm still failing to google, but there is hope: tomorrow I'll find this answer to my own question